# Python Homework - Not making sense

Tags: python, list, integer

OK, our professor explained (kinda) this problem, but it still doesn't make much sense.

Question: Implement the function `knice(f,a,b,k)` that will return 1 if for some integer `a <= x <= b` and some integer `n <= k`, n applications of `f` on x will be x, (e.g. `f(f(f...(f(x)))) = x`) and 0 if not.

What the professor provided was:

```
def knice(f,a,b,k):
    f(f(f(...(f(x)))) = x
    for i = a to b:
        y = f(i)
        if y = i break
    for j = z to k:
        y = f(y)
        if y = i break
```

Personally, that example makes no sense to me, so looking to see if I can get clarification.

**OP EDIT 1/19/2012 3:03pm CST**

This is the final function that was figured out with the help of the GTA:

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x-3

def knice(f,a,b,k):
x = a
while x <= b:
    n = 1
    y = f(x)
    if y == x:
        return 1
    while n <= k:
        y = f(y)
        n=n+1
        if y == x:
            return 1
    x=x+1   
return 0
```

Comment: I think the indenting is a bit off, the second `for` loop should probably be inside the first. Also, what is `z`? Finally, there is no `return` at all from this function. Is this example just a starting point or is it intended to be a working function?

Comment: That is the problem. The professor didn't specify what any of the example meant and he explained this to a class of 40 because NO ONE knew what to do. I honestly couldn't tell if it was a z or 2!

Comment: Ok, consider it a non-working starting point then. With some rearrangement and minor tweaks, you can make that function work.

Comment: @GregHewgill The professor put this up to be the working function, saying that the problem is "simple" and would use an algorithm very close, if not, exactly like this.

Comment: Well, you may have made mistakes copying the function then - you already said that `z` might have been `2`. What else would you change?

Comment: @seiryuu10: Clearly the professor is wrong if you can't even make sense of it, let alone get it to work as is. I do think that `z` should be a `2` though.

Comment: Hmm... if no one in your class got this, it might be a question better for your Professor or Teaching Assistants. Is he out of town or unreachable?

Comment: I could just be a case of "here's some pseudo-code of what I want you to do".

Comment: @tobier: given that the syntax of for loops is a bit off for straight python, you're spot on.

Comment: @seiryuu10 please! come back to SO with the answer when you get it (and post it)

Comment: Ok, I messed around with this today and tried a few things to see if I am getting the idea and thus far, NONE work. This is what I have tried thus far:

`def knice(f,a,b,k):
 for a in b:
  y = f(i)
  if y == i:
   break
  for j in k:
   y = f(y)
   if y == i:
    break
 return y`

and

`def knice(f,a,b,k):
 for i in a & b:
  y = f(i)
  if y == i:
   break
  for j in k:
   y = f(y)
   if y == i:
    break
 return y`

Comment: @joaquin I will post what I have when I figure out the answer. ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignore his code; you should write whatever you feel comfortable with and work out the kinks later.

You want to work out whether

- `f(a) = a`, or `f(f(a)) = a`, or ..., or `f^n(a) = a`, **or**,
- `f(a+1) = a+1`, or `f(f(a+1)) = a+1`, or ..., or `f^n(a+1) = a+1`, **or**,
- ...
- `f(b) = b`, or `f(f(b)) = b`, or ..., or `f^n(b) = b`.

An obvious algorithm should come to mind immediately: try all these values one-by-one! You will need two (nested) loops, because you are iterating over a rectangle of values. Can you now see what to do?

Comment: I do see it actually, but it is trying to code it that I am having the issues with. I had no formal or otherwise experience with Python and it was a "here you go, turn it in on the due date" thing.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, I can see why that might be confusing.

Was `f(f(f(...(f(x)))) = x` wrapped in triple-double-quotes? That's a function documentation string, sort of like commenting your code. It shouldn't have been stand-alone without something protecting it.

Imagine f was called increment_by_one.

Calling increment_by_one 10 times like that on an x of 2 would give 12. No matter how many times you increment, you never seem to get back 2.

Now imagine f was called multiply_by_one.

Calling multiply_by_one 5 times like that on an x of 3 would give 3. Sweet.

So, some example outputs you can test against (you have to write the functions)

`knice(increment_by_one, 1, 3, 5)` would return 0.

`knice(multiply_by_one, 1, 3, 5)` would return 1.

As another hint, indentation is important in python.

Comment: You really cleared this up. That prof's code makes almost *no* sense at all.

Comment: @Droogans: It is supposed to be close (in structure) to the final answer. The syntax isn't actually python, the "variables" in the code are placeholders for you to fill in, etc. If you do figure out the answer, though, you might find more similarities than differences in the professor's code (that's what Greg's second comment was about). The trick was understanding the complex goals of the function in the first place. If you've got a handle on that, good luck.

Comment: sorry to press the issue, but seeing another prof treat freshman this way makes me wonder if they gets their bonus measured against making them flunk out of the CS program. If I were at the lecture, I might have a different opinion about the 'example' posted here. `:)`

Comment: I'll press the devil's/profesor's advocate position: I don't think the prof is actively seeking to harm freshman-level understanding of the problem. Once you learn to program, it impacts how you think about such problems (and the examples you provide). Sure, it could be that your professor is out of touch with freshman-level thinking. But it could be that there are many ways to introduce the problem and your professor used one that didn't work for you. I'd hope that if you went to office hours, the prof would try a different approach, perhaps multiple approaches, until he saw it "click".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concrete example. Start small, and suppose you called `knice(f, a=1, b=2, k=1)`. For `k==1`, we don't have to worry about iterating the function. The only values of `x` to consider are 1 and 2, so `knice` can return 1 (i.e., True) if `f(1)==1` or `f(2)==2`.

Now suppose you called `knice(f, a=1, b=2, k=2)`. You'll have to check `f(f(1))` and `f(f(2))` as well.

As `k` gets bigger, you'll have to call `f` more. And as the range between `a` and `b` gets bigger, you'll have to try more values of `x` as an argument to `f`.